# Projection cannot be work using Specification JPA in Spring boot 3

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data, java-17

So I'm trying to use Specification with projection, this is a new feature on Spring Boot 3.1.3.

**Service**

```
public UserSimple bySpecification(Integer id) {
    Specification<UserInfo> spec = UserInfoSpecs.byId(id);
    UserSimple simpleList = repository.findBy(spec, q -> q.as(UserSimple.class).oneValue());
    return simpleList;
}
```

**Projection (Interface)**

```
public interface UserSimple {
    String getName();
}
```

**Specification**

```
public interface UserInfoSpecs {

    static Specification<UserInfo> byId(Integer id) {
        return (root, query, builder) ->
                builder.equal(root.get("id"), id);
    }

}
```

**Entity**

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserInfo {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;

}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface UserInfoRepository extends JpaRepository<UserInfo, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<UserInfo> {

    Optional<UserInfo> findByName(String username);
}
```

Response Hibernate SQL

*org.hibernate.SQL: select u1_0.id,u1_0.email,u1_0.name,u1_0.password,u1_0.roles from user_info u1_0 where u1_0.id=? fetch first ? rows only*

How to make hibernate mount the query like correct Projection:

**org.hibernate.SQL: select u1_0.name from user_info u1_0 where u1_0.id=? fetch first ? rows only**